# Como passar valor dentro do modal com PHP

Tags: php, modal

Estou tentando criar um botão de excluir para uma tabela. A exclusão será feia em duas etapas:
1. clica na lixeira 
2. confirma

Acredito que estou me confundindo na hora de passar o valor do $id pro modal.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Estoque</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Bootstrap theme -->
    <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
    <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">  
        <table class="table">
            <tr><b>
                <td>Código Produto</td>
                <td>Descrição</td>
                <td>Preço</td>
                <td>Quantidade Estoque</td>
            </tr></b>

    <?php
        REQUIRE_ONCE "conexao.php";
        $sql = "SELECT id, cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador FROM estoque";
        $result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
    ?>

            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bg ?>">
                <td><?php echo $row[cod_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[dsc_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[preco_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_estoque] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_limitador] ?></td>
                <td>
                    <form method="get" action="edit.php">
                        <button type="hidden" name="id" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $row[id]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                    </form>
                    <form method="POST" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                        <button type="button" name="botaoDelete" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" value="<?php echo $row[id] ?>" data-target="#myModal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    </form>
                </td>
            </tr>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Excluir produto</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Você tem certeza que deseja excluir?</p>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <form method="POST">
            <button type="button" name="botaoConfirma" value="<?php echo $dlt ?>" class="btn btn-danger">Excluir</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btnn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
        </form>

    <?php      
        if (isset($_POST["botaoDelete"])) {
            $dlt = $_POST["botaoDelete"];
            if (isset($_POST["botaoConfirma"])) {
                $cnf = $_POST["botaoConfirma"];
                $deleteSql = mysqli_query($conexao, "DELETE * FROM estoque WHERE id='".$cnf."'");
            }
        }
    }   
    ?> 

    </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
    </div><!-- /.modal -->
    </tbody>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Há alguma forma de passar valor de botão sem ser usando *form*?
E também, como posso chamar esse valor (caso o botão for pressionado) sem usar *if (isset)*? Vale a pena?

Comment: Qual o problema que está acontecendo?

Comment: Não está excluindo a linha desejada, ou seja, não estou conseguindo passar a ID até o botão "confirmar". Compensa eu utilizar java nessa parte mesmo focando no desenvolvimento em PHP? Ainda sou iniciante e isso me deixa confuso.

Comment: Tem vários jeitos de resolver isso, a forma mais simples de fazer isso seria, utilizar o `confirm()` do javascript, separar a exclusão do registro em arquivo a parte(talvez em uma função posteriormente ;]) se a resposta do `confirm()` for `true` vc redirecione para esse arquivo novo(excluir.php) caso não só da um `return false` na sua função javascript.

Comment: Mas se eu fizer essa função fora do arquivo, ele vai precisar sair da página ou consigo fazer tudo no modal? Como já havia dito, não seria uma boa prática tentar fazer isso com php uma vez que o código é basicamente todo em php?

Comment: Vai sair da pagina se for confirmada a exclusão, inicie dessa forma, depois vc pode fazer isso via ajax(ai sim não sai da tela nem da refresh na tela).

Answer (score 3):

Ó, pelo que eu entendi, é isso aqui que você fazer. Seguinte:

1º: Neste passo você chama o modal e, no metodo *onclick*, você passa o id que deseja. Vai colocar no botão de deletar um link:

```
<a href="#deletar-dado" role="button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="deletaDado(<?php echo $id ?>)" class="deletar">Excluir</a>
```

2º: Cria o seu modal da seguinte forma:

```
<div id="deletar-dado" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmação</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Deseja realmente excluir este registro?</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancelar</button>
            <a id="confirmaDelecao" class="btn red">Apagar</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

3º: criar uma funcao que js que vai receber o id do dado pra deletar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletaDado (idDado){
    //seta o caminho para quando clicar em "Apagar".
    var href = $('#confirmaDelecao')[0].baseURI + '/deletar/' + idDado;
    //adiciona atributo de delecao ao link
    $('#confirmaDelecao').prop("href", href);
}
</script>
```

Se precisar de alguma coisa, chama a gente ai. :D Valeu!

Comment: Eu não entendo muito bem javascript, mas eu não tenho que chamar essa função? Testei aqui o que você disse que o botão de confirmação não faz nada.

Comment: você chama ela dentro do onclick, lá no primeiro passo

Comment: Estou tendo teste.php/deletar/undefined na URL como retorno.

Comment: Você está colocando o id dentro do onclick?

Answer (score 0):

Seguindo as orientações do Matheus, obtive:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>




   <title>Estoque</title>

<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Bootstrap theme -->
<link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js" </script>
<script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">  
        <table class="table">
            <tr><b>
                <td>Código Produto</td>
                <td>Descrição</td>
                <td>Preço</td>
                <td>Quantidade Estoque</td>
            </tr></b>


<?php
REQUIRE_ONCE "conexao.php";
$sql = "SELECT id, cod_produto, dsc_produto, preco_produto, qtd_estoque, qtd_limitador FROM estoque";
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        { 

?>


            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $bg ?>">
                <td><?php echo $row[cod_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[dsc_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[preco_produto] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_estoque] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row[qtd_limitador] ?></td>



                <td>
                    <form method="get" action="edit.php">
                        <button type="hidden" name="id" class="btn btn-default" value="<?php echo $row[id]?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> </button>
                    </form>
                    <a href="#deletar-dado" role="button" data-toggle="modal" onclick="deletaDado(<?php echo $row[id]?>)" class="deletar">Excluir</a>
                </td>
                </tr>



    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="deletar-dado" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Confirmação</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Deseja realmente excluir este registro?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" data-dismiss="modal" class="btn default">Cancelar</button>
        <a id="confirmaDelecao" class="btn red">Apagar</a>
    </div>
</div>
</div>


</tbody>
</div>
<?php      

}   
?> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function deletaDado (idDado){
//seta o caminho para quando clicar em "Apagar".
var href = $('#confirmaDelecao')[0].baseURI + '/deletar/' + idDado;
//adiciona atributo de delecao ao link
$('#confirmaDelecao').prop("href", href);
}
</script>
</body>
```

Ao clicar no link apagar na tela de confirmação, nada acontece.

Comment: Cara, você tem que trocar o seu _href_ dentro da funcao de deletar.

Comment: Desculpa, mas eu ainda não entendo muito bem a sintaxe do javascript. Você poderia dar mais detalhes sobre isso? Se possível explicar o que cada elemento está fazendo na função, talvez isso ajude mais pessoas também.

Comment: você conseguiu resolver dessa forma?

Comment: Na verdade eu estou tentando usar SweetAlert no lugar, mas ainda estou tendo alguns problemas.